# Android OpenCV - Recognizing parts of a building

Tags: java, opencv, feature-extraction, android

I am creating an app to recognize a building or parts of a building to overlay certain highlights.
At first I thought about using Vuforia and Unity like everyone else does, but I feel like it does not give me the freedom I need, especially with the free version.

My logic goes a bit deeper than just using a target image, so my idea was to use Android Studio and OpenCV.

I am at a point, where I can show feature matching with steps like

`Calib3d.findHomography(pts1Mat, pts2Mat, Calib3d.RANSAC, 10, outPutMask, 2000, 0.995);`

to get good matches and then use

`Features2d.drawMatches(imgFromFile, keyPoints1, imgFromFrame, keyPoints2, better_matches_mat, outputImg);`

But at this moment I am kind of out of ideas on how to translate the seemingly easy python code you often find to android/java.

Things I need to do at this point:

1. Extract descriptors/keypoints from known images of the building so the app does not need to calculate those each time/frame (I will take many fotographs)
2. Highlight matching area (box or color highlights on contour)
3. Get rid of false positives (it finds matches even though I have the camera on some random object
4. Framerate kinda low atm with drawMatches, since I dont really need that I hope that the framerate will be better when "just" calculating matches
   I am trying to frameResolution/2 or frameResolution/4 before working with them but matches get worse

Some of my code

```
public Mat matching (Mat matFrame, int viewMode, int resizeMode) {

    if (viewMode == VIEW_MODE_FEATURES) {
        initMatching();
        if (!imageIsAnalyzed) {
            detectImageFromFile();
        }
        detectFrame(matFrame, resizeMode);
        featureMatching();
        outPutMat = drawingOutputMat();
    }
    return outPutMat;

private void initMatching () {
    detector = ORB.create();
    descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);
    matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);
}


private void featureMatching () {
    matcher.knnMatch(descriptor1, descriptor2, matches, 2);
    //ratio test to get good matches
    if (matOfDMatch.toArray()[0].distance / matOfDMatch.toArray()[1].distance < 0.9) {
            good_matches.add(matOfDMatch.toArray()[0]);
    }
    //....
for(int i = 0; i<good_matches.size(); i++) {
        pts1.add(keyPoints1.toList().get(good_matches.get(i).queryIdx).pt);
        pts2.add(keyPoints2.toList().get(good_matches.get(i).trainIdx).pt);
   }
//....
Calib3d.findHomography(pts1Mat, pts2Mat, Calib3d.RANSAC, 10, outPutMask, 2000, 0.995);
    //outPutMask contains zeros and ones indicating which matches are filtered
    better_matches = new LinkedList<DMatch>();
    for (int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++) {
        if (outPutMask.get(i , 0)[0] != 0.0) {
            better_matches.add(good_matches.get(i));
        }
    }
private void detectFrame (Mat matFrame, int resizeMode) {
    imgFromFrame = matFrame;
    Imgproc.resize(imgFromFrame, imgFromFrame, new Size(matFrame.width()/resizeMode, matFrame.height()/resizeMode));
    descriptor2 = new Mat();
    keyPoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

    detector.detect(imgFromFrame, keyPoints2);
    descriptor.compute(imgFromFrame, keyPoints2, descriptor2);
}
private Mat drawingOutputMat () {
    //Drawing Output
    outputImg = new Mat();

    better_matches_mat = new MatOfDMatch();
    better_matches_mat.fromList(better_matches);
    //this will draw all matches
    Features2d.drawMatches(imgFromFile, keyPoints1, imgFromFrame, keyPoints2, better_matches_mat, outputImg);
//Instead of the drawing matches I will need some classification and some overlay on the output
    return outputImg;
}
```

I hope some of you can help me to figure out my next steps and how I should continue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does noone know how I should proceed?